# Как получить страницу с русскими символами с помощью urllib [Python]

Tags: python

столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается получить страницу с русскими символами. Как это можно сделать?
Вот код:

```
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    s = str(f.read())
    print("результат: " + s)
```

Comment: А страница в какой кодировке на самом деле? И какой версии Python? Если Python 3-й и страница в UTF-8, то всё уже должно быть нормально. Или у вас url на русском?

Comment: @CrazyElf, Python 3. url не на русском. В кодировке страницы могу ошибиться так что не могу сказать точно, но русские символы заменяются на 16-ричку